# Trouble installing and running MongoDB on Mac

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install MongoDB on my Mac, running Yosemite. I downloaded Mongo using

```
$ curl -O http://downloads.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.4.tgz
```

Unpacked it:

```
$ tar -zxvf mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.4.tgz
```

Renamed the directory:

```
$ mv mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.4 mongodb
```

Created the data/db directory:

```
$ mkdir -p /data/db
```

Set folder permissions:

```
$ chown -R $USER /data/db
```

So far, so good. Now I want to run it. So:

```
$ cd mongodb/bin
$ mongod
```

And I get all these errors:

```
2015-06-20T18:35:18.558-0700 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=589 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Brian-ONeills-iMac.local

2015-06-20T18:35:18.558-0700 [initandlisten] 

2015-06-20T18:35:18.558-0700 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000

2015-06-20T18:35:18.558-0700 [initandlisten] db version v2.6.4

2015-06-20T18:35:18.558-0700 [initandlisten] git version: 3a830be0eb92d772aa855ebb711ac91d658ee910

2015-06-20T18:35:18.558-0700 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin bs-osx108-4 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49

2015-06-20T18:35:18.558-0700 [initandlisten] allocator: system

2015-06-20T18:35:18.558-0700 [initandlisten] options: {}

2015-06-20T18:35:18.639-0700 [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal

2015-06-20T18:35:18.639-0700 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed

2015-06-20T18:35:18.994-0700 [initandlisten] preallocateIsFaster=true 5.28

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] ****

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] ****

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] need to upgrade database local with pdfile version 4.22, new version: 4.5

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten]     Not upgrading, exiting

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten]     run --upgrade to upgrade dbs, then start again

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] ****

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] dbexit: 

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] journalCleanup...

2015-06-20T18:35:19.811-0700 [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles

2015-06-20T18:35:19.812-0700 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...

2015-06-20T18:35:19.812-0700 [initandlisten] dbexit: really exiting now
```

Any idea what could be going on and how to fix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried running `mongod --upgrade` as suggested in the messages? It looks like you have data files present from an older version of MongoDB.

Comment: I would also note that the only error in your output is the message that your data files were created with an older version of MongoDB (which causes MongoDB to shut down so you can upgrade the data files). The rest of the preceding output is normal messaging about the startup sequence.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If so, could you help the community by sharing how you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

These diagnostics suggest /data/db already had an earlier (older) version of mongodb installed.   Check out 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-upgrade/